# Oracle REGEX to format value to time

Tags: regex, oracle

I have the following code in Oracle to retrieve a value formatted as a DateTime:

```
E.EVE_START_DATE || ' ' || LPAD(NVL(TRIM(SUBSTR(AGD_START_TIME, 0, LENGTH(AGD_START_TIME)-2)), '00') || ':' || NVL(SUBSTR(AGD_START_TIME, -2), '00') || ':00', 8, '0') EVE_START_DATE
```

The AGD_STARTTIME column has it's data stored in this format:

```
 930
1330
1630
1730
```

I have been trying to rewrite this using a Regex but having issues.

```
E.EVE_START_DATE || ' ' || regexp_replace('0'||AGD_START_TIME,'.*([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$','\1:\2:00') EVE_START_DATE
```

But, I'm ending up with this returned data, why would only the 930 entry be messed up?

```
08-JUN-16 16:30:00
05-OCT-16 0 930
05-OCT-16 13:30:00
22-JUN-16 16:30:00
13-JUL-16 0 930
13-JUL-16 13:30:00
10-AUG-16 16:30:00
18-MAY-16 13:30:00
21-SEP-16 13:30:00
02-NOV-16 17:30:00
22-JUN-16 16:30:00
22-JUN-16 13:30:00
14-SEP-16 0 930
12-OCT-16 17:30:00
20-OCT-16 17:30:00
10-AUG-16 13:30:00
```

Comment: Because your regular expression looks for two digits, then two digits, while " 930" begins with a space and a digit.

Comment: Well, what would be the fix?

Comment: Uhm... look for a space or a digit?

Comment: Kind of helpful, aren't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nailed it 95% I think.

You just a extra space in front of `930`. `TRIM()` should solve it!

```
E.EVE_START_DATE || ' ' || regexp_replace('0'||TRIM(AGD_START_TIME),'.*([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$','\1:\2:00') EVE_START_DATE
```

**Sample:**

```
SQL> with my_data(AGD_START_TIME) as
  2  (
  3    select ' 930' from dual
  4    union all
  5    select '1330' from dual
  6    union all
  7    select '1630' from dual
  8    union all
  select '1730' from dual
  9   10  )
 11  select regexp_replace('0'||TRIM(AGD_START_TIME),'.*([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$','\1:\2:00') as str
from my_data; 12

STR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
09:30:00
13:30:00
16:30:00
17:30:00
```

Comment: @mustaccio missed out.

Comment: even if you trim space it will fail because of incorrect regex

Comment: No, it looks for last 4 digits. And padding '0' to left makes `930` to `0930`

Comment: i din't saw that you have padded with `0`..(

Comment: then, it seems I overthought it..my bad..(

Comment: That's ok. It happens!